# Get a view-class to show on main and run with the content from the view-class

Tags: java, javafx, program-entry-point

I have made a `PizzaMenuView` class containing a large amount of code e.g. the GUI stuff. I cannot get it to run in through the main. For some reason it does not show anything when I run the code.

Can someone tell me by looking at my two classes why it does not show anything. Maybe I am calling the methods wrongly? The `PizzaOrderingSystem` is my main, and the `PizzaMenuView` is the class I would like my main to run.

```
public class PizzaOrderingSystem extends Application {  

    private PizzaMenuView pizzaMenuView;


    //Creating Stage and making layout for the stage
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){


        pizzaMenuView = new PizzaMenuView();


        Scene scene = new Scene(pizzaMenuView, 650, 650);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Pizza Ordering System");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```
    public PizzaMenuView(){

        /*
        * Creating border1 which contain border2 in the top and grid2 in the center. 
        * border2 and contains hBoxTop and a grid1. 
        */      
        border1 = new BorderPane();
        border1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgrey");

        border1.setTop(border2);
        border1.setCenter(grid2);
        border1.setBottom(hBoxBottom);

        border2 = new BorderPane();
        // Attaching hbox, vboxes and grid to border2. 
        border2.setTop(hBoxTop);
        border2.setCenter(grid1);

        hBoxTop = new HBox();
        titel = new Text("Dortes pizza place");

        /**
        * Layout settings for the titel in the hBoxTop
        * Setting the linear gradient to go from lightblue to darkblue
        */
        Stop[] stops = new Stop[] { 
        new Stop(0, Color.LIGHTBLUE),  
        new Stop(1, Color.DARKSLATEBLUE)
        };  
        LinearGradient linearGradient = 
                          new LinearGradient(0, 1, 1, 0, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, stops); 

        // Adding the titel text to hBoxTop and selecting font, gradient color, and letter size.
        hBoxTop.getChildren().addAll(titel);
        titel.setFont(Font.font ("Verdana", 50));
        titel.setFill(Color.LIGHTBLUE); 
        titel.setStrokeWidth(2); 
        titel.setStroke(Color.DARKSLATEBLUE);
        titel.setFill(linearGradient); 

        // Making layout for hBoxTop
        hBoxTop.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hBoxTop.setPadding(new Insets(5, 30, 30, 5));
        hBoxTop.setMaxHeight(30);
        hBoxTop.setPrefHeight(30);
        hBoxTop.setFillHeight(false);

        // creating grid1 that is in the bottom of border1
        grid1 = new GridPane();

        // Styling the three columns for grid1.                
        titelCategoryColumn = new ColumnConstraints();
        titelCategoryColumn.setPercentWidth(40);
        titelCategoryColumn.setHalignment(HPos.LEFT);

        titelNameColumn = new ColumnConstraints();
        titelNameColumn.setPercentWidth(40);
        titelNameColumn.setHalignment(HPos.LEFT);

        titelPriceColumn = new ColumnConstraints();
        titelPriceColumn.setPercentWidth(40);
        titelPriceColumn.setHalignment(HPos.LEFT);


        // Adding columns to grid1
        grid1.getColumnConstraints().add(titelCategoryColumn);
        grid1.getColumnConstraints().add(titelNameColumn);
        grid1.getColumnConstraints().add(titelPriceColumn);


        //Styling and adding the row to the grid1
        row1 = new RowConstraints();
        row1.setPrefHeight(30);
        row1.setValignment(VPos.CENTER);
        row1.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
        grid1.getRowConstraints().add(row1);


        // Making text to add to grid1
        Text text1 = new Text("Category");
        text1.setFont(Font.font("verdana", FontWeight.BOLD, FontPosture.REGULAR, 20));
        Text text2 = new Text("Menu item");
        text2.setFont(Font.font("verdana", FontWeight.BOLD, FontPosture.REGULAR, 20));
        Text text3 = new Text("Price");
        text3.setFont(Font.font("verdana", FontWeight.BOLD, FontPosture.REGULAR, 20));


        // Adding text to grid1  
        grid1.add(text1, 1, 0);
        grid1.add(text2, 2, 0);
        grid1.add(text3, 3, 0);

        /*
        NOW TO BORDER1
        */

        // creating grid2 that is in the center of border1
        grid2 = new GridPane();

        // Styling the column for the grid2
        checkBoxColumn = new ColumnConstraints();
        checkBoxColumn.setPercentWidth(20);
        checkBoxColumn.setHalignment(HPos.CENTER);

        categoryColumn = new ColumnConstraints();
        categoryColumn.setPercentWidth(40);
        categoryColumn.setHalignment(HPos.LEFT);

        nameColumn = new ColumnConstraints();
        nameColumn.setPercentWidth(40);
        nameColumn.setHalignment(HPos.LEFT);

        priceColumn = new ColumnConstraints();
        priceColumn.setPercentWidth(40);
        priceColumn.setHalignment(HPos.LEFT);


        //styling rows for grid2.
        row2 = new RowConstraints();
        row2.setPrefHeight(100);
        row2.setValignment(VPos.CENTER);
        row2.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);


        // Getting and defining arrayList with menuItems from the Class OrderMenu
        menu = new OrderMenu();
        ArrayList<MenuItem> menuItems = menu.menuItems;

        // Adding columns to grid2
        grid2.getColumnConstraints().add(checkBoxColumn);
        grid2.getColumnConstraints().add(categoryColumn);
        grid2.getColumnConstraints().add(nameColumn);
        grid2.getColumnConstraints().add(priceColumn);

        /**
         * For loop gets size of arrayList and diving them into objects 
         * which makes it possible for them to be assigned to the grid.
         */
        for (int item = 0; item < menuItems.size(); item++) {

            // Set the styling for row2
            grid2.getRowConstraints().add(row2);

            // Get the required info out of each item
            String category = menuItems.get(item).category;
            String name = menuItems.get(item).name;
            double price = menuItems.get(item).price;

            // Add the text to the grid2
            Text categoryText = new Text(category);
            categoryText.setFont(Font.font("verdana", FontPosture.REGULAR, 15));
            Text nameText = new Text(name);
            nameText.setFont(Font.font("verdana", FontPosture.REGULAR, 15));
            Text priceText = new Text(Double.toString(price) + " DKK");
            priceText.setFont(Font.font("verdana", FontPosture.REGULAR, 15));
            CheckBox check = new CheckBox ();
            check.setStyle("-fx-focused-color: lightblue");

            // Adding columns to grid1
            grid2.add(check, 0, item);
            grid2.add(categoryText, 1, item);
            grid2.add(nameText, 2, item);
            grid2.add(priceText, 3, item);


            hBoxBottom = new HBox();  
            // Making layout for hBoxBottom.  
            hBoxBottom.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_RIGHT);
            hBoxBottom.setPadding(new Insets(20, 50, 50, 50));
            hBoxBottom.setMaxHeight(70);
            hBoxBottom.setPrefHeight(70);
            hBoxBottom.setFillHeight(false);

            Button button = new Button("Add selected items to basket");
            button.setFont(Font.font("verdana", FontPosture.REGULAR, 15));
            button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: LIGHTBLUE");
            button.setMinHeight(50);
            hBoxBottom.getChildren().add(button);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you want people to take the time and provide a solution to your question, then you should take the time to format, write clearly and double check your question before posting it. In your question you say that you try to run your code through 'the main', but it doesn't work. Then you say that when you run your code directly from the main, it works. Make your question readable and understandable and you will get a reply in no-time!
Also, try to not post all of your code in a question, but rather only the important parts.

Comment: Hi! I have just tried to rephrase myself, I hope it is easier to understand and I have uploaded the entire class with all of the code, because I am not sure whats causing the error.

Comment: What do you mean by: `"I cannot get it to run in through the main"` ?

Comment: What kind of `Node` is `PizzaMenuView`? You don't seem to add anything the child list of the `PizzaMenuView` itself!

Comment: I dont understand your question. I am new at java, so theres a lot of things that is new to me. PizzaMenuView is my other class, the one containing all of my borderPanes, grids ect. I dont think that is a node. I am trying to get the content running trough my main class by calling the other class, that is what I mean by "I cant get it to run trough the main".

Comment: `Scene`'s second constructor parameter is `Parent` (which extends `Node`). For your code to compile therefore `pizzaMenuView`'s type (= `PizzaMenuView`) must be assignable to `Parent`, but it may indirectly extend `Parent`. What is `PizzaMenuView`'s superclass (`public class PizzaMenuView extends <superclass>`; post the identifier that takes the place of `<superclass>`; if there's none your code shouldn't compile, since your type is not assignable to `Parent` for obvious reasons).

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you create all of your GUI items inside the constructor of `PizzaMenuView` (could be better to organize the code in a more easy-to-handle way), then in the main method you make this:

```
this.pizzaMenuView.border1 = new BorderPane();
```

That is, you create a new instance of `BorderPane` and store it in `this.pizzaMenuView.border1`, overwriting the current reference.

Just try to comment out that line.

### Edit

Try with the following:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(pizzaMenuView.border1, 650, 650);
```

The reason is that `Scene` [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#Scene-javafx.scene.Parent-double-double-) is expecting an argument of type `Parent`, which is a node that can be shown in the user interface, while pizzaMenuView is not a Node (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html)).

Comment: Ive tried to change it in the code, but it still does not show anything except from the empty stage. It is like it cant read the content from the other class. You can see what I have changed in my code example above.

Comment: Ive now tried to do these changes and uncommenting everything except the border1 in the other class with its grid in the center, but for some reason nothing runs now. I can see that it attempts to run but clothes before it does anything?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you mean, but if you get some errors, you should post what error you get so that someone can help you. Anyway, my answer just sets `BorderPane` object referenced by `border1` as the first argument for the `Scene` constructor, without the necessity to comment other parts of code. See also the other comments on your question and try to understand how code and JavaFX work, so that you can debug your code fast and successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question *"I can't get this to run through the main"*, then you want to create an instance of `PizzaMenuView()` inside `PizzaOrderingSystem.main()`.

What you seem to be doing in PizzaOrderingSystem's **main method**, is call the `launch()` method, which is a method that `PizzaOrderingSystem()` class inherits from its **parent class**.

> *The parent class is `Application()`, that `PizzaOrderingSystem()` extends from.*

You can find [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html) the java documentation for `Application()`. Or click [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.String...-), to simply read about what `launch(String... args)` does.

So, in order to create an instance of `PizzaMenuView()`, you need to do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //Instance of PizzaMenuView()
    PizzaMenuView menu = new PizzaMenuView();
}
```

**NOTE:**
You are already creating an instance of `PizzaMenuView()` in`PizzaOrderingSystem.start()`, but since I don't know how your program works, I'm pointing out the most obvious way to run the instance of the class you want (considering that you initialize everything in `PizzaMenuView()`'s constructor).